# How to use a busy indicator when resizing kendo splitter?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-splitter, kendo-progressbar

Where would I place a Kendo UI busy indicator in here? I did have it placed in the resize event, but it wouldn't fire

Here is the indicator

```
kendo.ui.progress($("#container"), true);
kendo.ui.progress($("#container"), false);
```

```js
let ds = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Jane",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 25,
    gender: "female",
    city: "London",
    country: "England"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 26,
    gender: "male",
    city: "London",
    country: "Canada"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "James",
    lastname: "Jones",
    age: 30,
    gender: "male",
    city: "New York",
    country: "US"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Mary",
    lastname: "Johnson",
    age: 23,
    gender: "female",
    city: "Paris",
    country: "France"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Robert",
    lastname: "Lee",
    age: 44,
    gender: "male",
    city: "Berlin",
    country: "Germany"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Jane",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 25,
    gender: "female",
    city: "London",
    country: "England"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 26,
    gender: "male",
    city: "London",
    country: "Canada"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "James",
    lastname: "Jones",
    age: 30,
    gender: "male",
    city: "New York",
    country: "US"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "Mary",
    lastname: "Johnson",
    age: 23,
    gender: "female",
    city: "Paris",
    country: "France"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Robert",
    lastname: "Lee",
    age: 44,
    gender: "male",
    city: "Berlin",
    country: "Germany"
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    name: "Jane",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 25,
    gender: "female",
    city: "London",
    country: "England"
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 26,
    gender: "male",
    city: "London",
    country: "Canada"
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: "James",
    lastname: "Jones",
    age: 30,
    gender: "male",
    city: "New York",
    country: "US"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    name: "Mary",
    lastname: "Johnson",
    age: 23,
    gender: "female",
    city: "Paris",
    country: "France"
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    name: "Robert",
    lastname: "Lee",
    age: 44,
    gender: "male",
    city: "Berlin",
    country: "Germany"
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    name: "Jane",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 25,
    gender: "female",
    city: "London",
    country: "England"
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    name: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 26,
    gender: "male",
    city: "London",
    country: "Canada"
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    name: "James",
    lastname: "Jones",
    age: 30,
    gender: "male",
    city: "New York",
    country: "US"
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    name: "Mary",
    lastname: "Johnson",
    age: 23,
    gender: "female",
    city: "Paris",
    country: "France"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    name: "Robert",
    lastname: "Lee",
    age: 44,
    gender: "male",
    city: "Berlin",
    country: "Germany"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  //$.when(RunMySplitters()).then(LoadTopGrid(), LoadBottomGrid());
  LoadTopGrid();
  LoadBottomGrid();
  RunMySplitters();

});

function RunMySplitters() {
  let splitterPosition = "middle";

  $("#vertical-n")
    .kendoSplitter({
      orientation: "vertical",
      panes: [{
        collapsible: false
      }]
    });

  $("#horizontal")
    .kendoSplitter({
      panes: [{
          collapsible: true,
          size: "10%",
          collapsed: false
        },
        {
          collapsible: true,
          size: "90%"
        }
      ],
      collapse: function(e) {},
      resize: function(e) {

      },
      expand: function(e) {

      }
    });
  let hSplitterBar = $('#horizontal').data("kendoSplitter");
  hSplitterBar.max("#left-pane", "10%");

  $("#innerVertical")
    .kendoSplitter({
      orientation: "vertical",
      panes: [{
          collapsible: true,
          size: '50%'
        },
        {
          collapsible: true,
          size: '50%',
          //collapsed: apiHome.IsImplementor //TAsk 11 Changes add collapsed:true
        }
      ],
      collapse: function(e) {

        if (e.pane.id === "top-pane" && splitterPosition === "bottom") {
          splitterPosition = "middle";
        } else if (e.pane.id === "top-pane" && splitterPosition === "middle") {
          splitterPosition = "top";
        } else if (e.pane.id === "bottom-pane" && splitterPosition === "top") {
          splitterPosition = "middle";
        } else if (e.pane.id === "bottom-pane" && splitterPosition === "middle") {
          splitterPosition = "bottom";
        }

      },
      resize: function(e) {
        console.log("Resizing");
        let tGrid = $('#TopGrid').getKendoGrid();
        let bGrid = $('#BottomGrid').getKendoGrid();

        tGrid.setOptions({
          height: $('#innerVertical #top-pane').height()
        });
        bGrid.setOptions({
          height: $('#innerVertical #bottom-pane').height()
        });
      },
      expand: function(e) {

        if (e.pane.id === "top-pane" && splitterPosition === "top") {
          splitterPosition = "middle";
        } else if (e.pane.id === "top-pane" && splitterPosition === "middle") {
          splitterPosition = "bottom";
        } else if (e.pane.id === "bottom-pane" && splitterPosition === "bottom") {
          splitterPosition = "middle";
        } else if (e.pane.id === "bottom-pane" && splitterPosition === "middle") {
          splitterPosition = "top";
        }

      }
    });

  let topBar = $('#innerVertical').data("kendoSplitter");
  topBar.max("#top-pane", "75%");
  topBar.max("#bottom-pane", "75%");
}

function LoadTopGrid() {
  $('#TopGrid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: ds,
      schema: {
        model: {
          id: "id",
          fields: {
            id: {
              editable: false,
              type: "number"
            },
            name: {
              editable: true,
              type: "string"
            },
            lastname: {
              editable: true,
              type: "string"
            },
            age: {
              editable: false,
              type: "number"
            },
            gender: {
              editable: false,
              type: "string"
            },
            city: {
              editable: true,
              type: "string"
            },
            country: {
              editable: true,
              type: "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "id",
        title: "ID",
        width: "50px",
        locked: true
      },
      {
        field: "name",
        title: "First",
        width: "150px",
        attributes: {
          class: "editable-cell"
        },
        locked: true
      },
      {
        field: "lastname",
        title: "Last",
        width: "150px",
        attributes: {
          class: "editable-cell"
        },
        locked: true
      },
      {
        field: "age",
        title: "Age",
        width: "50px"
      },
      {
        field: "gender",
        title: "Gender",
        width: "100px"
      },
      {
        field: "city",
        title: "City",
        width: "100px"
      },
      {
        field: "country",
        title: "Country",
        width: "100px"
      }
    ],
    navigatable: true,
    editable: {
      mode: "incell",
      confirmation: false
    },
    selectable: "row",
    change: function(e) {
      console.log("I changed!");
    },
    resizable: true,
    height: $('#innerVertical #top-pane').height()
  });
}

function LoadBottomGrid() {
  $('#BottomGrid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: ds,
      schema: {
        model: {
          id: "id",
          fields: {
            id: {
              editable: false,
              type: "number"
            },
            name: {
              editable: true,
              type: "string"
            },
            lastname: {
              editable: true,
              type: "string"
            },
            age: {
              editable: false,
              type: "number"
            },
            gender: {
              editable: false,
              type: "string"
            },
            city: {
              editable: true,
              type: "string"
            },
            country: {
              editable: true,
              type: "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "id",
        title: "ID",
        width: "50px",
        locked: true
      },
      {
        field: "name",
        title: "First",
        width: "150px",
        attributes: {
          class: "editable-cell"
        },
        locked: true
      },
      {
        field: "lastname",
        title: "Last",
        width: "150px",
        attributes: {
          class: "editable-cell"
        },
        locked: true
      },
      {
        field: "age",
        title: "Age",
        width: "50px"
      },
      {
        field: "gender",
        title: "Gender",
        width: "100px"
      },
      {
        field: "city",
        title: "City",
        width: "100px"
      },
      {
        field: "country",
        title: "Country",
        width: "100px"
      }
    ],
    resizable: true,
    navigatable: true,
    editable: {
      mode: "incell",
      confirmation: false
    },
    selectable: "row",
    change: function(e) {
      console.log("I changed!");
    },
    height: $('#innerVertical #bottom-pane').height()
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html,
#horizontal,
#innerVertical,
#vertical
/*#TopGrid,
    #BottomGrid*/

{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top-pane {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bottom-pane {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
<div id="container">
  <div id="vertical-n" style="height:100%;">
    <div id="top-pane">
      <div id="horizontal">
        <div id="left-pane" style="border: 1px solid yellow;background-color: yellow;">
          <div class="pane-content"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="right-pane">
          <div id="innerVertical">
            <div id="top-pane" style="width: 100%;border: 1px solid blue;background-color: blue;">
              <div class="pane-content">
                <div id="TopGrid"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bottom-pane" style="width: 100%;border: 1px solid green;background-color: green;">
              <div class="pane-content">
                <div id="BottomGrid"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately all of the events are triggered after the size has changed and not while the size is changing. The only alternative that I could think of is a hack in that you would set a timeout whenever the mouse is down on the splitter bar and toggle the busy icon.

Comment: @David, sounds like a good idea